# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, procedural-programming

There is an error on the procedure which I call on my program. Please help me to fix this, it is making me confused :(. I got a message like this: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1"

This is the source code of the procedure:

```
    BEGIN
DECLARE tampung  VARCHAR(1000);
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS xxx_sensusdaftar_rajal;
SET @tabel = 'create TEMPORARY table xxx_sensusdaftar_rajal( tglreg date, shift1 int, pasienbaru int, kdpoly int, P int, L int, poly_rj1 int, poly_rj2 int, poly_rj3 int, poly_rj4 int, polyrujukan int, ';
select group_concat(concat('carabayar_kd',kode,' int') separator ', ') into tampung from m_carabayar order by kode;
set @tabel = concat(@tabel,tampung,')');
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @tabel;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
set @insert1 = "insert into xxx_sensusdaftar_rajal
select a.tglreg,a.shift,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly,
sum( if(b.jeniskelamin='P',1, null)) as P,
sum(if(b.jeniskelamin='L', 1, null ))as L,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-1)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd1,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/2*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-2)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd2,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/3*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-3)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd3,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/4*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-4)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd4,
cast(sum(kdpoly/11*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-11)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli_kd11,";
set tampung = '';
select group_concat(concat('cast(sum(a.kdcarabayar/',kode,'*(1-abs(sign(a.kdcarabayar-',kode,')))) as UNSIGNED ) as carabayar_kd',kode) separator ', ') into tampung from m_carabayar order by kode;
set @insert1 = concat(@insert1,tampung," FROM t_pendaftaran a , m_pasien b
where a.kdpoly=1 and a.nomr=b.nomr and tglreg between '",inTANGGAL,"' and '",inTANGGAL2,"' GROUP BY a.tglreg,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly
union
select a.tglreg,a.shift,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly,
sum( if(b.jeniskelamin='P',1, null)) as P,
sum(if(b.jeniskelamin='L', 1, null ))as L,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-1)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd1,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/2*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-2)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd2,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/3*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-3)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd3,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/4*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-4)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd4,
cast(sum(kdpoly/11*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-11)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli_kd11,");
set @insert1 = concat(@insert1,tampung," FROM t_pendaftaran a , m_pasien b
where a.kdpoly=2 and a.nomr=b.nomr and tglreg between '",inTANGGAL,"' and '",inTANGGAL2,"' GROUP BY a.tglreg,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly
union
select a.tglreg,a.shift,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly,
sum( if(b.jeniskelamin='P',1, null)) as P,
sum(if(b.jeniskelamin='L', 1, null ))as L,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-1)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd1,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/2*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-2)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd2,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/3*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-3)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd3,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/4*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-4)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd4,
cast(sum(kdpoly/11*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-11)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli_kd11,");
set @insert1 = concat(@insert1,tampung," FROM t_pendaftaran a , m_pasien b
where a.kdpoly=3 and a.nomr=b.nomr  and tglreg between '",inTANGGAL,"' and '",inTANGGAL2,"' GROUP BY a.tglreg,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly
union
select a.tglreg,a.shift,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly,
sum( if(b.jeniskelamin='P',1, null)) as P,
sum(if(b.jeniskelamin='L', 1, null ))as L,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-1)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd1,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/2*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-2)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd2,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/3*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-3)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd3,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/4*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-4)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd4,
cast(sum(kdpoly/11*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-11)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli_kd11,");
set @insert1 = concat(@insert1,tampung," FROM t_pendaftaran a , m_pasien b
where a.kdpoly=4 and a.nomr=b.nomr  and tglreg between '",inTANGGAL,"' and '",inTANGGAL2,"' GROUP BY a.tglreg,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly
union
select a.tglreg,a.shift,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly,
sum( if(b.jeniskelamin='P',1, null)) as P,
sum(if(b.jeniskelamin='L', 1, null ))as L,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-1)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd1,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/2*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-2)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd2,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/3*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-3)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd3,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/4*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-4)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd4,
cast(sum(kdpoly/11*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-11)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli_kd11,");
set @insert1 = concat(@insert1,tampung," FROM t_pendaftaran a , m_pasien b
where a.kdpoly=5 and a.nomr=b.nomr  and tglreg between '",inTANGGAL,"' and '",inTANGGAL2,"' GROUP BY a.tglreg,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly
union
select a.tglreg,a.shift,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly,
sum( if(b.jeniskelamin='P',1, null)) as P,
sum(if(b.jeniskelamin='L', 1, null ))as L,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-1)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd1,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/2*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-2)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd2,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/3*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-3)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd3,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/4*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-4)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd4,
cast(sum(kdpoly/11*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-11)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli_kd11,");
set @insert1 = concat(@insert1,tampung," FROM t_pendaftaran a , m_pasien b
where a.kdpoly=6 and a.nomr=b.nomr  and tglreg between '",inTANGGAL,"' and '",inTANGGAL2,"' GROUP BY a.tglreg,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly
union
select a.tglreg,a.shift,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly,
sum( if(b.jeniskelamin='P',1, null)) as P,
sum(if(b.jeniskelamin='L', 1, null ))as L,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-1)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd1,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/2*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-2)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd2,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/3*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-3)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd3,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/4*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-4)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd4,
cast(sum(kdpoly/11*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-11)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli_kd11,");
set @insert1 = concat(@insert1,tampung," FROM t_pendaftaran a , m_pasien b
where a.kdpoly=7 and a.nomr=b.nomr  and tglreg between '",inTANGGAL,"' and '",inTANGGAL2,"' GROUP BY a.tglreg,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly
union
select a.tglreg,a.shift,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly,
sum( if(b.jeniskelamin='P',1, null)) as P,
sum(if(b.jeniskelamin='L', 1, null ))as L,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-1)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd1,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/2*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-2)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd2,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/3*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-3)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd3,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/4*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-4)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd4,
cast(sum(kdpoly/11*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-11)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli_kd11,");
set @insert1 = concat(@insert1,tampung," FROM t_pendaftaran a , m_pasien b
where a.kdpoly=8 and a.nomr=b.nomr  and tglreg between '",inTANGGAL,"' and '",inTANGGAL2,"' GROUP BY a.tglreg,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly
union
select a.tglreg,a.shift,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly,
sum( if(b.jeniskelamin='P',1, null)) as P,
sum(if(b.jeniskelamin='L', 1, null ))as L,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-1)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd1,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/2*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-2)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd2,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/3*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-3)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd3,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/4*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-4)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd4,
cast(sum(kdpoly/11*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-11)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli_kd11,");
set @insert1 = concat(@insert1,tampung," FROM t_pendaftaran a , m_pasien b
where a.kdpoly=28 and a.nomr=b.nomr  and tglreg between '",inTANGGAL,"' and '",inTANGGAL2,"' GROUP BY a.tglreg,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly
union
select a.tglreg,a.shift,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly,
sum( if(b.jeniskelamin='P',1, null)) as P,
sum(if(b.jeniskelamin='L', 1, null ))as L,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-1)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd1,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/2*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-2)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd2,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/3*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-3)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd3,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/4*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-4)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd4,
cast(sum(kdpoly/11*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-11)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli_kd11,");
set @insert1 = concat(@insert1,tampung," FROM t_pendaftaran a , m_pasien b
where a.kdpoly=29 and a.nomr=b.nomr  and tglreg between '",inTANGGAL,"' and '",inTANGGAL2,"' GROUP BY a.tglreg,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly
union
select a.tglreg,a.shift,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly,
sum( if(b.jeniskelamin='P',1, null)) as P,
sum(if(b.jeniskelamin='L', 1, null ))as L,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-1)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd1,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/2*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-2)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd2,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/3*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-3)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd3,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/4*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-4)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd4,
cast(sum(kdpoly/11*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-11)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli_kd11,");
set @insert1 = concat(@insert1,tampung," FROM t_pendaftaran a , m_pasien b
where a.kdpoly=30 and a.nomr=b.nomr  and tglreg between '",inTANGGAL,"' and '",inTANGGAL2,"' GROUP BY a.tglreg,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly
union
select a.tglreg,a.shift,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly,
sum( if(b.jeniskelamin='P',1, null)) as P,
sum(if(b.jeniskelamin='L', 1, null ))as L,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-1)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd1,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/2*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-2)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd2,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/3*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-3)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd3,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/4*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-4)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd4,
cast(sum(kdpoly/11*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-11)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli_kd11,");
set @insert1 = concat(@insert1,tampung," FROM t_pendaftaran a , m_pasien b
where a.kdpoly=9 and a.nomr=b.nomr  and tglreg between '",inTANGGAL,"' and '",inTANGGAL2,"' GROUP BY a.tglreg,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly
union
select a.tglreg,a.shift,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly,
sum( if(b.jeniskelamin='P',1, null)) as P,
sum(if(b.jeniskelamin='L', 1, null ))as L,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-1)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd1,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/2*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-2)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd2,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/3*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-3)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd3,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/4*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-4)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd4,
cast(sum(kdpoly/11*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-11)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli_kd11,");
set @insert1 = concat(@insert1,tampung," FROM t_pendaftaran a , m_pasien b
where a.kdpoly=10 and a.nomr=b.nomr  and tglreg between '",inTANGGAL,"' and '",inTANGGAL2,"' GROUP BY a.tglreg,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly
union
select a.tglreg,a.shift,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly,
sum( if(b.jeniskelamin='P',1, null)) as P,
sum(if(b.jeniskelamin='L', 1, null ))as L,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-1)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd1,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/2*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-2)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd2,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/3*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-3)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd3,
cast(sum(a.kdrujuk/4*(1-abs(sign(a.kdrujuk-4)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poly_rujuk_kd4,
cast(sum(kdpoly/11*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-11)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli_kd11,");
set @insert1 = concat(@insert1,tampung," FROM t_pendaftaran a , m_pasien b
where a.kdpoly=11 and a.nomr=b.nomr  and tglreg between '",inTANGGAL,"' and '",inTANGGAL2,"' GROUP BY a.tglreg,a.pasienbaru,a.kdpoly;");
PREPARE stmt2 FROM @insert1;
EXECUTE stmt2;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS xxx_sensusdaftar_rajal2;
SET @tabel2 = 'create TEMPORARY table  xxx_sensusdaftar_rajal2(
tglreg date,
shift1 int,
pasienbaru varchar(10),
P int,
L int,
poli1_rj1 int,
poli2_rj1 int,
poli3_rj1 int,
poli4_rj1 int,
poli5_rj1 int,
poli6_rj1 int,
poli7_rj1 int,
poli8_rj1 int,
poli9_rj1 int,
poli10_rj1 int,
poli28_rj1 int,
poli29_rj1 int,
poli30_rj1 int,
poli1_rj2 int,
poli2_rj2 int,
poli3_rj2 int,
poli4_rj2 int,
poli5_rj2 int,
poli6_rj2 int,
poli7_rj2 int,
poli8_rj2 int,
poli9_rj2 int,
poli10_rj2 int,
poli28_rj2 int,
poli29_rj2 int,
poli30_rj2 int,
poli1_rj3 int,
poli2_rj3 int,
poli3_rj3 int,
poli4_rj3 int,
poli5_rj3 int,
poli6_rj3 int,
poli7_rj3 int,
poli8_rj3 int,
poli9_rj3 int,
poli10_rj3 int,
poli28_rj3 int,
poli29_rj3 int,
poli30_rj3 int,
poli1_rj4 int,
poli2_rj4 int,
poli3_rj4 int,
poli4_rj4 int,
poli5_rj4 int,
poli6_rj4 int,
poli7_rj4 int,
poli8_rj4 int,
poli9_rj4 int,
poli10_rj4 int,
poli28_rj4 int,
poli29_rj4 int,
poli30_rj4 int,
rujukan int,';
set tampung = '';
select group_concat(concat('crbyr',kode,' int') separator ', ') into tampung from m_carabayar order by kode;
set @tabel2 = concat(@tabel2,tampung,', total int);');
PREPARE stmt3 FROM @tabel2;
EXECUTE stmt3;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
set @insert2 = "insert into xxx_sensusdaftar_rajal2
select tglreg, a.shift1,case a.pasienbaru when 0 then 'LAMA'  when 1 then 'BARU' end as pasienbaru,
sum(P) as P,
sum(L) as L,
cast(sum(poly_rj1*kdpoly*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-1)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli1_rj1,
cast(sum(poly_rj1*kdpoly/2*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-2)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli2_rj1,
cast(sum(poly_rj1*kdpoly/3*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-3)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli3_rj1, 
cast(sum(poly_rj1*kdpoly/4*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-4)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli4_rj1,
cast(sum(poly_rj1*kdpoly/5*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-5)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli5_rj1,
cast(sum(poly_rj1*kdpoly/6*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-6)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli6_rj1,
cast(sum(poly_rj1*kdpoly/7*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-7)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli7_rj1,
cast(sum(poly_rj1*kdpoly/8*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-8)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli8_rj1,
cast(sum(poly_rj1*kdpoly/9*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-9)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli9_rj1,
cast(sum(poly_rj1*kdpoly/10*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-10)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli10_rj1,                        
cast(sum(poly_rj1*kdpoly/28*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-28)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli28_rj1,
cast(sum(poly_rj1*kdpoly/29*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-29)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli29_rj1,
cast(sum(poly_rj1*kdpoly/30*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-30)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli30_rj1,
cast(sum(poly_rj2*kdpoly*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-1)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli1_rj2,
cast(sum(poly_rj2*kdpoly/2*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-2)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli2_rj2,
cast(sum(poly_rj2*kdpoly/3*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-3)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli3_rj2, 
cast(sum(poly_rj2*kdpoly/4*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-4)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli4_rj2,
cast(sum(poly_rj2*kdpoly/5*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-5)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli5_rj2,
cast(sum(poly_rj2*kdpoly/6*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-6)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli6_rj2,
cast(sum(poly_rj2*kdpoly/7*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-7)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli7_rj2,
cast(sum(poly_rj2*kdpoly/8*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-8)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli8_rj2,
cast(sum(poly_rj2*kdpoly/9*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-9)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli9_rj2,
cast(sum(poly_rj2*kdpoly/10*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-10)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli10_rj2,
cast(sum(poly_rj2*kdpoly/28*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-28)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli28_rj2,
cast(sum(poly_rj2*kdpoly/29*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-29)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli29_rj2,
cast(sum(poly_rj2*kdpoly/30*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-30)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli30_rj2,
cast(sum(poly_rj3*kdpoly*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-1)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli1_rj3,
cast(sum(poly_rj3*kdpoly/2*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-2)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli2_rj3,
cast(sum(poly_rj3*kdpoly/3*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-3)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli3_rj3, 
cast(sum(poly_rj3*kdpoly/4*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-4)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli4_rj3,
cast(sum(poly_rj3*kdpoly/5*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-5)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli5_rj3,
cast(sum(poly_rj3*kdpoly/6*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-6)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli6_rj3,
cast(sum(poly_rj3*kdpoly/7*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-7)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli7_rj3,
cast(sum(poly_rj3*kdpoly/8*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-8)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli8_rj3,
cast(sum(poly_rj3*kdpoly/9*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-9)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli9_rj3,
cast(sum(poly_rj3*kdpoly/10*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-10)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli10_rj3,
cast(sum(poly_rj3*kdpoly/28*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-28)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli28_rj3,
cast(sum(poly_rj3*kdpoly/29*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-29)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli29_rj3,
cast(sum(poly_rj3*kdpoly/30*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-30)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli30_rj3,
cast(sum(poly_rj4*kdpoly*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-1)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli1_rj4,
cast(sum(poly_rj4*kdpoly/2*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-2)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli2_rj4,
cast(sum(poly_rj4*kdpoly/3*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-3)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli3_rj4, 
cast(sum(poly_rj4*kdpoly/4*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-4)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli4_rj4,
cast(sum(poly_rj4*kdpoly/5*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-5)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli5_rj4,
cast(sum(poly_rj4*kdpoly/6*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-6)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli6_rj4,
cast(sum(poly_rj4*kdpoly/7*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-7)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli7_rj4,
cast(sum(poly_rj4*kdpoly/8*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-8)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli8_rj4,
cast(sum(poly_rj4*kdpoly/9*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-9)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli9_rj4,
cast(sum(poly_rj4*kdpoly/10*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-10)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli10_rj4,
cast(sum(poly_rj4*kdpoly/28*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-28)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli28_rj4,
cast(sum(poly_rj4*kdpoly/29*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-29)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli29_rj4,
cast(sum(poly_rj4*kdpoly/30*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-30)))) as UNSIGNED ) as poli30_rj4,
cast(sum(poly_rj1*kdpoly/11*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-11)))) as UNSIGNED ) +
cast(sum(poly_rj2*kdpoly/11*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-11)))) as UNSIGNED ) +
cast(sum(poly_rj3*kdpoly/11*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-11)))) as UNSIGNED ) +
cast(sum(poly_rj4*kdpoly/11*(1-abs(sign(kdpoly-11)))) as UNSIGNED ) as rujukan,";
set tampung = '';
select group_concat(concat('sum(carabayar_kd',kode,') as crbyr',kode) separator ', ') into tampung from m_carabayar order by kode;
set @insert2 = concat(@insert2,tampung,', ');
set tampung = '';
select group_concat(concat('sum(carabayar_kd',kode,')') separator '+') into tampung from m_carabayar order by kode;
set @insert2 = concat(@insert2,tampung," as total
FROM xxx_sensusdaftar_rajal a GROUP BY tglreg, a.pasienbaru
ORDER BY tglreg DESC;");
PREPARE stmt4 FROM @insert2;
EXECUTE stmt4;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt4;
set @select = "select shift1, pasienbaru,
sum(P) as P,
sum(L) as L,
sum(poli1_rj1) as poli1_rj1,
sum(poli2_rj1) as poli2_rj1,
sum(poli3_rj1) as poli3_rj1,
sum(poli4_rj1) as poli4_rj1,
sum(poli5_rj1) as poli5_rj1,
sum(poli6_rj1) as poli6_rj1,
sum(poli7_rj1) as poli7_rj1,
sum(poli8_rj1) as poli8_rj1,
sum(poli9_rj1) as poli9_rj1,
sum(poli10_rj1) as poli10_rj1,
sum(poli28_rj1) as poli28_rj1,
sum(poli29_rj1) as poli29_rj1,
sum(poli30_rj1) as poli30_rj1,
sum(poli1_rj2) as poli1_rj2,
sum(poli2_rj2) as poli2_rj2,
sum(poli3_rj2) as poli3_rj2,
sum(poli4_rj2) as poli4_rj2,
sum(poli5_rj2) as poli5_rj2,
sum(poli6_rj2) as poli6_rj2,
sum(poli7_rj2) as poli7_rj2,
sum(poli8_rj2) as poli8_rj2,
sum(poli9_rj2) as poli9_rj2,
sum(poli10_rj2) as poli10_rj2,
sum(poli28_rj2) as poli28_rj2,
sum(poli29_rj2) as poli29_rj2,
sum(poli30_rj2) as poli30_rj2,
sum(poli1_rj3) as poli1_rj3,
sum(poli2_rj3) as poli2_rj3,
sum(poli3_rj3) as poli3_rj3,
sum(poli4_rj3) as poli4_rj3,
sum(poli5_rj3) as poli5_rj3,
sum(poli6_rj3) as poli6_rj3,
sum(poli7_rj3) as poli7_rj3,
sum(poli8_rj3) as poli8_rj3,
sum(poli9_rj3) as poli9_rj3,
sum(poli10_rj3) as poli10_rj3,
sum(poli28_rj3) as poli28_rj3,
sum(poli29_rj3) as poli29_rj3,
sum(poli30_rj3) as poli30_rj3,
sum(poli1_rj4) as poli1_rj4,
sum(poli2_rj4) as poli2_rj4,
sum(poli3_rj4) as poli3_rj4,
sum(poli4_rj4) as poli4_rj4,
sum(poli5_rj4) as poli5_rj4,
sum(poli6_rj4) as poli6_rj4,
sum(poli7_rj4) as poli7_rj4,
sum(poli8_rj4) as poli8_rj4,
sum(poli9_rj4) as poli9_rj4,
sum(poli10_rj4) as poli10_rj4,
sum(poli28_rj4) as poli28_rj4,
sum(poli29_rj4) as poli29_rj4,
sum(poli30_rj4) as poli30_rj4,
sum(rujukan) as rujukan,";
set tampung = '';
select group_concat(concat('sum(crbyr',kode,') as crbyr',kode) separator ', ') into tampung from m_carabayar order by kode;
set @select = concat(@select,tampung,', sum(total) as total from xxx_sensusdaftar_rajal2 group by pasienbaru;');
PREPARE stmt5 FROM @select;
EXECUTE stmt5;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt5;
  END
```

Comment: You don't even know anything about the code above, do you? Anything at all. To you, it's just a huge chunk of un-understandable code. lol

Comment: OP, As the MySQL interpreter tells you... "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')'"

Comment: @Femalia Halim :you can avoid such type issues if you create a new procedure from any gui like sqlyog etc as it will provide you correct proc format with delimeters and you just need to put your code between it. Actually in stored procedure/function we use multiple sql statements so to let mysql know that all sql statements are related with single block of code we need to use delimeter.

Answer (score 1):

I swear I just tested this on my system. As opposed to cut and paste of the whole thing to show you, merely wrap all you have inside of this

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure blahblah789()

(ALL OF YOUR STUFF)

$$
DELIMITER ;
```

It works, meaning, no 1064 Syntax Error. Were I to run it, well clearly I would not have the tables.

You need to **delimit** it. Give it a shot

Manual page [Using Delimiters with MySqlScript](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-mysqlscript-delimiter.html)

Comment: Thanks I'll try it :)